# Linux Arch Unity not writeable settings

Tags: linux, arch-linux, unity

I am running Linux Arch with KDE till yet. Now I want to move to Unity because of some personal favors. I used the tutorial proposed in the arch wiki for installation (the recommended way using the repositories). https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/unity#From_repository_.28recommended.29

The ui seems to be running fine, except that I can't change a lot of settings. For example:

I can't set an option to the nautilus, to the gnome-terminal, to the compiz config manager. I also can't add a program to my starter. Everything gets reset one second after I set an option. So it seems to me like a permissions problem, that I have no write access to my profile configs, but I don't know how to tackle it.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. There were some problems with my home folder. A clear new user had no problems. So i backed up my home folder and deleted everything excepting the thunderbird, mozilla and steam folders. Now its running like a charm.